# How do I take an unspecified amount of inputs separated by space in a single line using scanf?

Tags: c

I want to be able to take a single line of multiple integers, of any varying values, separated by a space and turn them into the following graph-like output. The number of integer values is unspecified

```
In: 1 2 3
Out: 
1 | *
2 | **
3 | ***
```

or

```
In: 12 16 18 4 17
Out:
12 | ************
16 | ****************
18 | ******************
4  | ****
17 | *****************
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you try so far?

Comment: @Mathieu I can't figure out a way to take all my input in a single line. Everywhere else shows me that the inputs are entered on a new line.

Comment: `scanf()` is not the best way, but if you insist, read them in as a string, `"%s"`,  then parse them using a parsing function based on `strtok()`.  Better, read them in as a line buffer, then parse the same way using a space delimited `strtok()` loop.  But if you do not show what you have tried, your question will likely be closed.

Comment: Read the line via `%[^\n]` specifier of `scanf()` (I think `fgets()` is better, but the question is "using scanf") and parse the line.

Comment: How will the output be when the input is `1 2 10`? (This is for checking if reading the whole input is required before starting output)

Comment: @MikeCAT The output would be like the second example, but I guess the line would be shifted back one space for single digits.

Comment: Scanf doesn't distinguish between newlines and spaces.  Reading with `%d` in a loop will work just fine.

Comment: @WilliamPursell How do I solve the part about an unspecified amount of inputs. It could be 3 inputs like %d, %d, %d or it could be 5.

Comment: If there will be only one line in the input, read until the input fails. It can be checked like `scanf("%d", &num) == 1`.

Comment: I suggest to read the line with `fgets` and use `strtol` in a loop to convert the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't at all understand why you feel the need to grab all the input "in one line".  If you want to treat newlines differently than spaces, scanf if probably the wrong tool.  But you could do something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
        int i;
        while( scanf("%d", &i) == 1 ){
                int t;
                printf("%d\t| ", i);
                while( i-- > 0 ){
                        putchar('*');
                }
                putchar('\n');
                if( (t = getchar()) == '\n' || t == EOF ){
                        break;
                }
                ungetc(t, stdin);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

But it seems like all the silliness with the logic of looking for a newline should simply be omitted.